# Invoke-Expression parameter not being used

Tags: powershell, batch-file, start-process

I have a working, simple batch file cmd:

```
D:\Software\MySoftware.exe --process MyConfig.tuc
```

When I try to replicate in Powershell using either Invoke-Expression or the call operator '&', the code executes but the log indicates it has not picked up the switch:  --process MyConfig.tuc

```
Invoke-Expression "D:\Software\MySoftware.exe --process MyConfig.tuc"
```

Or

```
& D:\Software\MySoftware.exe --process MyConfig.tuc
```

Edit: I've discovered that if you pass the full path of the .tuc file, the command is successful.

```
Invoke-Expression "D:\Software\MySoftware.exe --process D:\Software\MyConfig.tuc"
```

Comment: I have no idea what `Invoke-Expression` has to do with your task. Have you tried, `D:\Software\MySoftware.exe --process MyConfig.tuc`? If your actual path includes spaces, you may find that `& D:\Software\MySoftware.exe --process MyConfig.tuc` works better for you. If you want to use a command, then `Start-Process` may help you, `Start-Process -FilePath D:\Software\MySoftware.exe -ArgumentList "--process MyConfig.tuc"`.

Comment: Obviously if your executable isn't searching a known or relative path for the file in the argument, you'll need to provide that location or change your working directory as needed. `Start-Process` has a `-WorkingDirectory` option for that too.

Comment: Instead of adding the solution to the question you should better post it as an answer...

Comment: @Compo you are correct. If you wish to post as answer, I will accept.  This works:  Start-Process -FilePath D:\Software\MySoftware.exe -WorkingDirectory D:\Software  -ArgumentList "--process MyConfig.tuc"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question asked why Invoke-Expression needed the full path to the config file when the batch file did not.  As stated in comments by @compo this is likely due differences in how PS or cmd work in regard to relative paths.

@compo made the more pertinent observation that Start-Process would be a better solution, which I found it was.  Not only does it work, it has switches well suited to my needs, notably -wait which Invoke-expression was not natively doing (I couldn't confirm if it could wait, there are suggestions online it can).

```
Start-Process -FilePath D:\Software\MySoftware.exe -WorkingDirectory D:\Software  -ArgumentList "--process MyConfig.tuc" -wait
```